# Dropping columns from a where clause can i use the ? operator

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I cannot help but feel this is very slopy and there is more that I can do to cut this down.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? id)
{
    List<ClubMembers> clubs = new List<ClubMembers>();
    Guid.TryParse(UserId.ToString().ToUpper(), out
    Guid guidResult);
        
    if (id == null)
       clubs = await _context.ClubMembers.Where(w =>  
        w.isActive == true && w.isDeleted == false)
       .Include(c => c.Role)
       .Include(c => c.User)
       .Where(w => w.isActive == true
       && w.isDeleted == false).ToListAsync();
   else
      clubs = await _context.ClubMembers.Where(w => 
      w.ClubId == id && w.isActive == true && w.isDeleted
      == false).Include(c => c.Role).Include(c => c.User)
     .Where(w => w.isActive == true 
      && w.isDeleted == false).ToListAsync();

   ClubMembersViewModal clubMembersViewModal = new ClubMembersViewModal();
   clubMembersViewModal.Clubusers = clubsMembers;
   clubMembersViewModal.ClubInvitesViewModal = new ClubInvitesViewModel();
   clubMembersViewModal.ClubInvitesViewModal.ClubId = ClubId;
   clubMembersViewModal.ClubInvitesViewModal.FromMember = Email;
   clubMembersViewModal.ClubInvitesViewModal.ToMember = "test@gmail.com";
return View(clubMembersViewModal);

}
```

As I am just removing the need for one column the w.ClubId == in the first query is their not a cleaner way of just removing the column from the one query at all seems sloppy to do it this way?.

Could I use the null check operation ? in some where as part of the where clause? I just want it to not filter ClubId  if no id is passed.

Comment: Why do you have the `.Where()` filter twice in your query?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `IQueryable<T>` to construct your query step by step, like this.

```
IQueryable<ClubMembers> queryable = _context.ClubMembers
    .Where(w => w.isActive == true && w.isDeleted == false)
    .Include(c => c.Role).Include(c => c.User);

if (id != null)
    queryable = queryable.Where(w => w.ClubId == id);

clubs = await queryable.ToListAsync();
```